# homomorphism from ZxZ to Q

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have this problem. I like to find ring homomorphism from $(\mathbb Q,+,-)$ to ($\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z,+,-)$ and
homomorphism from $(\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z,+,-)$ to $(\mathbb Q,+,-)$.

My solution:

Let f is homomorphism. Suppose that $f(1)=(a,b)$, with $a,b∈\mathbb Z$. Since $f$ is a ring homomorphism it follows that in particular, $f(q)=f(q⋅1)=q⋅f(1)=q(a,b)$, with $q∈\mathbb Q$. 
That is all I did, becauseI do not know the next step.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you want ring homomorphisms? These should map identities to identities.

Comment: Yes ring homomorphisms.

Comment: @Alex that's not universally accepted terminology. The people who say "rings with unity" don't require the identity to be sent to the identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from $x \mapsto (0, 0)$ (if you allow that as a ring homomorphism), no such ring homomorphism can exist from $\Bbb{Q}$ to $\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}$, because if $f$ were a ring homomorphism from $\Bbb{Q}$ to $\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}$, then $f(1/2)$ would be an element, $x$ say, of $\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}$ such that $2x = (1, 1)$, which is impossible.

As for the oppositve direction, $(x, y) \mapsto x$ and $(x, y) \mapsto y$ both define ring homomorphisms from $\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}$ to $\Bbb{Z}\subseteq\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: In my reading, OP explicitly said he was taking the two structures to be additive groups. There still is no such homomorphism, in either direction.

Comment: Rob's argument works for additive groups as well, if you take 2x to mean x + x.  There is no element (a,b) where (a,b) + (a,b) = (1,1) but for every q not equal to zero there is (q/2) so (q/2) + (q/2) = q.

Comment: @Lubin: which part of OP's comment "yes ring homomorphisms" is explicitly saying that the structures of interest are additive groups?

Comment: He said at the outset “$(\Bbb Q,+,-)$”. I stopped reading right there, unfortunately. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is there no ring homomorphism, but there is no nontrivial group homomorphism $\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$, and there are only two nontrivial ring homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Q$.

The group $(\Bbb Q,+)$ is *divisible*, that is, for every $g\in\Bbb Q$ and every nonzero $n\in\Bbb Z$, there is $g'\in\Bbb Q$ such that $ng'=g$. However, you can easily see that the image (under a homomorphism) of a divisible group must be divisible. The only divisible subgroup of $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ is the trivial subgroup.

An idempotent $e$ in a ring $R$ is an element such that $e^2=e$; a homomorphism must take idempotents to idempotents. The ring $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ has four such elements, namely $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $0,1)$, and $(1,1)$. The answer of Rob Arthan correctly identifies the homomorphisms that take $(1,0)$ and $0,1)$ to $1\in\Bbb Q$; any homomorphism taking $(1,1)$ to $1\in\Bbb Q$ must be one of these, since if both go to $1$, then $(1,1)\mapsto2\in\Bbb Q$, not an idempotent. So there are only two nontrivial ring homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: (0,1) is idempotent in the ring $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ with the binar operation + ? I have got (0,1) + (0,1) = (0,2)

Comment: “Idempotent” in a ring always means with respect to multiplication. $(0,1)\cdot(0,1)=(0,1)$. The only idempotent in the additive structure of a ring will be the zero element, cause the additive structure is always a group.

Answer (score 0):

$Q(p/q) \to  Z(p,q)$

$p/q+r/s = (ps + qr)/qs$
The addition operation in $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$
has to be defined as: $(p,q) + (r,s) = (ps+qr,qs)$

Comment: Your notation doesn't make any sense.

Comment: But it's not onto.  Nothing is mapped to (2,4) or any (a,b) gcd(a,b) $\ne$ 1.

Comment: Also I think it's clear the OP wanted the addition operation preserved.

Comment: There is an equivalence relation such that (a,b) is equivalent to (ka,kb)